# Why does this strange character encoding happen?

Tags: html-entities

This HTML source code:

```
<td class="result">'DIVIS&Atilde;O DE EDUCA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O
PR?ESCOLAR E ENSINO PRIM&Aacute;RIOO'</td>
```

displays as:
'DIVISÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO PR?ESCOLAR E ENSINO PRIMÁRIOO'

Yeah, these are some Portuguese characters. 
Why does `&Atilde`; stand for Ã?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&Atilde; is an entity much like &nbsp ;
```

It stands for a unicode point which defines the character A with a tilde on top.

This effect is not due to any special character encoding. The entity is defined in all common encodings. Have a look at ISO-8859-1:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: -1 for reformatting using code, and bringing in the whole topic of encodings -- encoding doesn't matter here, and the OP didn't mention it, so stick to entities

Answer (score 6):

That's just HTML character entities. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)'s a whole list. `&Atilde;` stands for the Ã character because it's a reasonable name for an A with a ~ over it ;-)

Comment: +1 for adding the reference ... and not posting your answer in code

Comment: "character _entity_", not "character _encoding_".